# How to reference a entity twice in the same table but with different variables?

Tags: mysql, sql, reference

I really hope I have used the right vocabulary, since I usually don't do this in English.

My problem is the following: I want to create a table that references to the same entity in another table twice, but with different variables.
In detail, I want to create a table called "matches" that references twice to the entity "name" in a table called "club", since a sports match obviously has two teams participating. This is what I tried to do:

```
CREATE TABLE aclub (
    clubname varchar(100),
    stadium varchar(100),
    foundingdate integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (clubname, stadium) ) ;

CREATE TABLE amatches (
    matchnr integer PRIMARY KEY,
    place varchar(100) REFERENCES aclub(stadium),
    clubname1 varchar(100) REFERENCES aclub(clubname),
    clubname2 varchar(100) REFERENCES aclub(clubname) ) ;
```

The error I get is the following:

> ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "aclub"

Comment: Show your schema.

Comment: The `clubname` column in `aclub` needs to be `UNIQUE` (i.e.  a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`).  You can't create a `FOREIGN KEY` referencing a column that isn't `UNIQUE`.  Either make that column `UNIQUE` or the `PRIMARY KEY`, or change the referenced column to be the one that is.

Comment: @Siyual `clubname` is a `PRIMARY KEY`, however I have two `PRIMARY KEY`s in `aclub` which are both referenced in `matches`. Maybe I use the wrong code for that? `PRIMARY KEY (clubname, stadium)`.

I will edit the OP to provide more information.

Comment: @PM77-1 By schema you mean my ERM? Sorry, my English is really bad in this particular topic.

Comment: [Database Schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema)

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use synthetic primary keys.  This really makes it easier to design and use the data model:

```
CREATE TABLE aclub (
    aclubId int auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    clubname varchar(100),
    stadium varchar(100),
    foundingdate integer,
    UNIQUE (clubname, stadium)
) ;

CREATE TABLE amatches (
    matchnr integer auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    aclubid integer,
    foreign key (aclubid) references aclub(aclubid)
) ;
```

Your specific problem is that *all* the columns in a primary key need to be included in the foreign key definition.  But why bother?  Just use an auto-incremented id for the key and look up the information you want for the other fields.

Comment: Thank you. This works fine in the `aclub` table, but I need `amatches` to include 2 different clubnames and I think this one doesn't do that.

So basically my problem right now is that I need `amatches` to show 2 `clubname`s or `aclubid`s from 2 different clubs. However, I don't know how to reference to two entities twice, but with different variables.

Comment: @hacker1337ninja . . . If the clubs have different stadiums, then this allows multiple clubs in `aclub`.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE aclub (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    clubname varchar(100),
    stadium varchar(100),
    foundingdate integer,
    UNIQUE (clubname),
    UNIQUE (stadium)
) ;

CREATE TABLE amatches (
    matchnr INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    club1 INTEGER REFERENCES aclub(id),
    club2 INTEGER REFERENCES aclub(id),
    place INTEGER REFERENCES aclub(id)
) ;
```

So you are have three references to the aclub table as in your question. But now we are using integers instead of varchar and that reduces redundancy